# Cocos2d and hierarchial animations

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone

I'm creating a pixel-art isometric tactics game using cocos2d. The units are done with sprite sheets. I have a concept of gearing units up which would provide the units with certain stat boosts.

The problem comes when i start thinking about animating these sprites. If the equipment shows in game, how can i animated these pieces? So i researched around and found something called hierarchcial animations.

I wanted to ask,

1) are there any libraries, tools that people built for this purpose? Seems like there should be something i can use

2) if not, is it complicated to implement? How would i do it? Im afraid if i animate each part, things will go out of sync.

Comment: Have a look at Spine (http://esotericsoftware.com/).  Could fit your needs and it has a nice integration with Cocos2D and other game/graphics SDKs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it seems that Spine is mostly for line art thou. The art direction I wanted to go is pixel art

Comment: Potentially you could still use a tool like Spine render to texture at a low resolution and scale it up to fill the screen on a final pass.  Not sure if that's what you want but would give a pixel look.